# Cannot install curl-config in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, configuration, curl, r

When trying to install the R package `RCurl` I get the following error:

```
checking for curl-config... no
Cannot find curl-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
```

Yet, curl-config exists in the system:

```
$ curl-config --version
libcurl 7.43.0
```

Though it lays in the anaconda folder

```
$ which curl-config:
.../anaconda/bin/curl-config
.../anaconda/pkgs/curl-7.43.0-0/bin/curl-config
```

So I try to install it properly so that R finds it. Since I read curl-config comes with libcurl3-openssl-dev, I tried to install it, but it complains about dependencies:

```
$ apt-get install libcurl3-openssl-dev:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.22.0-3ubuntu4) but 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.10 is to be installed
                        Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: librtmp-dev but it is not going to be installe
```

(according to `sudo apt-get -f install` everything is fine)

How shoud I proceed?

**Edit**

```
$ apt-cache policy libcurl4-openssl-dev
libcurl4-openssl-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.22.0-3ubuntu4
  Version table:
     7.22.0-3ubuntu4 0
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

**Update**

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libcurl4-openssl-dev is a `security` package. I enabled the security repositories in `sources.list` and `libcurl4-openssl-dev` was successfully installed.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libcurl4-openssl-dev libcurl3` and give me a ping with @A.B.

Comment: The package `libcurl3-openssl-dev` isn't available for Precise. Is that a typo?

Comment: @A.B. edit done. No, it is not a typo. In theory, I should install libcurl4 (http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/FAQ.html) but the dependency error (the same as shown for libcurl3) made me think I should try with libcurl3 instead.

Comment: Actually what made me think I needed libcurl3 is that I read curl-config comes with libcurl3-openssl-dev and not with libcurl4-openssl-dev http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/curl-config.1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version for `libcurl4-openssl-dev` is `7.22.0-3ubuntu4.14` and not `7.22.0-3ubuntu4`. Therefore the installation of `libcurl3` is blocked.

Use the main server

```
sudo sed 's/http:\/\/fr\./http:\/\//' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And you should check, if you have enabled `precise-security` and `precise-updates` in <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd> in the tab <kbd>Updates</kbd>.

Now upgrade your system

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Note, that `/usr/bin/curl-config` is available in the packages

- `libcurl4-gnutls-dev`
- `libcurl4-nss-dev`
- `libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I could install libcurl4-gnutls-dev this way:

`sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list` and add these two lines at the end of the file

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security restricted main multiverse universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates restricted main multiverse universe
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```